# Sum up JSON array items by common key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Im facing a tricky problem in forming a JSON array.

```
I have a below JSON where products are duplicated, 

    var mainJson = [{
    "product": "pen",
    "quantity": 3
}, {
    "product": "pen",
    "quantity": 3
}, {
    "product": "pencil",
    "quantity": 4
}, {
    "product": "pencil",
    "quantity": 4
}]
```

now i want to remove the duplicated and i want to add **Quantity** field and my final output should look like below...

```
var finalOutput = [{
"product":"pen",
"quantity":6
},{
"product":"pencil",
"quantity":8
}]
```

Im able to remove the duplicate records with same product name but im not able to concatenate the quantity field at the time of elimination..

Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may walk through your source array, using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and insert into resulting array item, having `product` value found for the first time, or add current `quantity` should one already exist:

```js
const mainJson = [{"product":"pen","quantity":3},{"product":"pen","quantity":3},{"product":"pencil","quantity":4},{"product":"pencil","quantity":4}],
      groupped = mainJson.reduce((res,{product,quantity}) => {
        const group = res.find(item => item.product == product)
        group ?
        group.quantity += quantity : 
        res.push({product,quantity})
        return res
      }, [])
    
console.log(groupped)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```

**EDIT:**

Above algorithm (having O(n²) time complexity) will perform nicely when the number of unique product items is relatively small, however for large number of product items, it [is reasonable](https://jsbench.me/wck6hurfy4/1) (just like [@CameronDowner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60150504/11299053) and [@StepUp](http://StepUp) suggest) to build up a sort of hash map (first pass) with products and respective totals and transform that into array of desired format (second pass) which makes it O(n) time complexity:

```js
const mainJson = [{"product":"pen","quantity":3},{"product":"pen","quantity":3},{"product":"pencil","quantity":4},{"product":"pencil","quantity":4}],
      groupObj = mainJson.reduce((r,{product,quantity}) => 
                  (r[product] = (r[product]||0) + quantity, r), {}),
      group = Object.keys(groupObj).map(key => ({product:key, quantity: groupObj[key]}))

console.log(group)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```

Comment: @StepUp : as the number of unique product items approaches to source array size, look-backs performed by `find()` *may* perform slower than playing around with data types. However, I don't think it is a good idea to mess things up even further with overwriting `Object.values()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in two stages. First I would [reduce the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) into an object, with the `product` as the key and the `quantity` as the value.

This handles the duplicates very well because object keys can never be duplicated.

I would then map this, using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), back to an array in the desired format. Using [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) can make this step very clean.

```
const mainJson = [
  {
    product: "pen",
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    product: "pen",
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    product: "pencil",
    quantity: 4
  },
  {
    product: "pencil",
    quantity: 4
  }
];

const productQuantities = mainJson.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { product, quantity } = curr;
  const currentValue = acc[product] || 0; // default to zero if not set yet
  return {
    ...acc,
    [product]: currentValue + quantity
  };
}, {});

console.log(productQuantities);

const productQuantitiesArray = Object.entries(
  productQuantities
).map(([product, quantity]) => ({ product, quantity }));

console.log(productQuantitiesArray);
```

Comment: You're correct here, I think performance hit on this solution is also because my reduce function creates a new object each time to keep it as a pure function

Comment: You're right that this approach still reduces the performance, but pure functions have a lot of benefits and reduce unintended side effects so I'm not sure it's right to call it a flaw

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov it looks like my similar solution depends on implementation of `Object.values`. However, we can rewrite this method to avoid performance disadvantages. [Test results](https://jsbench.me/n9k6hrbq5e/2)

Comment: @CameronDowner you can avoid performance disadvantages by using `Object.values( yourObjectHere )`.

Comment: @StepUp : Looks like, `Object.keys()` [may resolve](https://jsbench.me/wck6hurfy4/1) your concerns nice and easy without playing around with native code

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov [It looks like simple loop is a great choice](https://jsbench.me/1lk6hv3ujp/1)

Comment: ...naah, `for..` loops are beyond my aesthetic threshold should they perform even twice as fast :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `reduce` function:

```
const result = mainJson.reduce( (a, {product, quantity})=> {
   a[product] = a[product] || {product, quantity: 0};
   a[product].quantity += quantity;
   return a;
},{})
```

An example:

```js
var mainJson = [{
  "product": "pen",
  "quantity": 3
}, {
  "product": "pen",
  "quantity": 3
}, {
  "product": "pencil",
  "quantity": 4
}, {
  "product": "pencil",
  "quantity": 4
}];

const result = mainJson.reduce( (a, {product, quantity})=> {
  a[product] = a[product] || {product, quantity: 0};
  a[product].quantity += quantity;
  return a;
},{})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

If you are bothering about performance, then you can use the following solution.

```
const result = mainJson.reduce( (a, {product, quantity})=> {
  a[product] = a[product] || {product, quantity: 0};
  a[product].quantity += quantity;
  return a;
},{})    

let vals = [];
for (var key in result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
        vals.push(result[key]);
    }
}

console.log(vals);
```

[You can see results at JSBench.me](https://jsbench.me/1lk6hv3ujp/1)

Comment: The code should return pen as 6, and pencil as 8, but it's returning 3 and 4, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

While the `reduce` method is quite Javascript, if you prefer a more generic way, you can do it in two steps:

1. Iterate over your JSON and create a `Map` with no duplicated items;
2. Iterate over the `Map` and get your final JSON.

Take in mind this solution is the hard way, and it is **slower** than the `reduce` method. I will not blame you if you keep with the nicer `reduce` option, I just wanted to point out this more generic way! The result is the same.

Following the steps, we have:

```js
var mainJson = [{"product": "pen","quantity": 3}, {"product": "pen","quantity": 3}, 
{"product": "pencil","quantity": 4}, {"product": "pencil","quantity": 4}];

// Step 1
var mapJson = new Map();
for(let item of mainJson)
{
    if (mapJson.has(item.product))
        mapJson.set(item.product, mapJson.get(item.product) + item.quantity);
    else
        mapJson.set(item.product, item.quantity);
}

// Step 2
var finalJson = [];
for(let item of mapJson)
    finalJson.push({product:item[0], quantity:item[1]});

console.log(finalJson);
```